# Why doesn't writerow separate these list elements?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a Wikipedia table but every time I run this code the excel file doesn't separate the values as it should and just puts the row inside a cell when it should separate the Year,Winner, etc inside different columns each.

I tried to test it by running it directly with a list inside writerow() and the result was the same.

```
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FIFA_World_Cup_finals"
html = urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FIFA_World_Cup_finals")
wiki_bs_obj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = wiki_bs_obj.find_all("table", {"class": re.compile(r"^wikitable")})[1]
rows = table.find_all("tr")
csv_file = open(r"C:\Users\odeig\Desktop\Scraped data\Football_cups.csv", "w", newline="")
writer = csv.writer(csv_file, dialect="excel")
try:
    csv_rows = []
    for row in rows:
        csv_row = []
        for cell in row.find_all(["td", "th"]):
            if cell.get_text().strip() != "":
                csv_row.append(cell.get_text().strip())
        csv_rows.append(csv_row)
    writer.writerows(csv_rows)
finally:
    csv_file.close()
```

In the link is a picture of the excel output I get when I run this code.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN3Cz.png

About the minimal reproducible example, I'll put it below, the problem is still the same, when opening this in excel it still puts the row in one cell.

```
data = ["This", "Is", "A", "Test"]
csv_file_test = open("test.csv", "w", newline="")
writer_test = csv.writer(csv_file_test)
writer_test.writerow(data)
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: Your code is not minimal: in includes a lot of set-up data acquisition that is unrelated to your question.  Post the output you get, as well as a trace that shows the difference between what you got and what you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output is fine when opening the csv file from Libre Office or Google spreadsheets.

**Proof**: [image]

I think the problem is with how excel imported this file. Check Excel settings for that, I'd look for the separator character first.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was exactly what Samy said, you can manually change your separator in excel and another solution would be to set de delimiter of the CSV writer to the one excel uses by default in your machine, in my case it was a semicolon so it'd be:

```
writer = csv.writer(csv_file, dialect="excel", delimiter=";")
```